# How to dynamically change content passed to puppet template.erb

Tags: puppet

I have a puppet module which generates a number of files based on an array passed

```
define writeFile{  
file { "/tmp/test.$name.conf":
  ensure => file,   
  content => template($testmodule::my_config_template),
}   
}


writeFile{$testmodule::ids:}
```

the value of $testmodule::ids: is any array say [1,2,3]. 
The above will generate test.1.conf,test.2.conf,test.3.conf but inside the conf i have a variable say id, which i have to modify based on the value.

but if i use file_line to modify file and update the id, it will change the mdhash and at next puppet run it will regenerates all the configs and will update id. This will happens during every puppet run.

How to dynamically modify the content passed to template during puppet run?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a little bit of difficulty figuring out whether or not you're wanting to call the define, 3 times, one for each id, and have one file with each id, or call it once and have it put all 3 ids into one file without messing up the order. I'm guessing the latter since with the former you wouldn't have an issue with the hash changing and the file rewriting each time.

One thing you might try is putting your IDs into a string in an explicit order when writing the file. You can do this in the puppet class/defined type with an inline template:

`$sorted_ids = inline_template('<%= @ids.sort.join(",") %>')`

So this would set the $sorted_ids variable string to `1,2,3` in your example. In the template you'd just need a line:

`id = [<%= @sorted_ids %>]`

Which, after variable interpolation, would generate a line like:

`id = [1,2,3]`

You could also just add the sorting straight to the template that the defined type creates, which hides the logic a bit from a user editing just the puppet class:

`id = [<%= @ids.sort.join(",") %>]`

This way, if you add another item to the ids array the sorting will change, but it should be consistent between runs where the array doesn't change, and so shouldn't cause the hash to update and the file to update. I think you can also apply this same logic to file_line, but you'd need to test it out to see.

Answer (score 0):

Simply

id <%= name -%>

in the template works like a charm